# Custom Message Encoder WCF - invalid signature

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, wcf-security

I tried to use the same service as @Misiu like in:
[Custom MessageEncoder add attributes to message without modifying structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002290/custom-messageencoder-add-attributes-to-message-without-modifying-structure)

I know that post has 3 years but I hope someone knows the answer.
I'm facing the same problem.

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://dz3.swd.zbp.pl/broker3/services/QueryDz. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know the ins and outs of the issue. The above error mainly indicates that the service certificate is not properly configured when we make the service work over `HTTPS`, as the error mentioned. In order to make WCF service work over `HTTPS`, we should add a service endpoint with transport security mode.

```
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService3.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="mybinding" contract="WcfService3.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="mybeh"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Subsequently, if the WCF project is hosted in IIS, we should add an https binding and bind a certificate in the IIS site binding module.
[image]
If the service is self-hosted, we could bind a certificate to a specific port by using the following command.

```
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:8000 certhash=0000000000003ed9cd0c315bbb6dc1c08da5e6 appid={00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF}
```

Please refer to the below documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-a-port-with-an-ssl-certificate
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.